# Sub setting shape file to plot a region and addressing mismatch in ggplot & data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

I am plotting India's district map with data (cases). First I read data for each district and district shape file. Later I merge the two on district. Using fortify data I get ggplot. I get a beautiful plot using ggplot.

```
##nr1 <- read.csv("../OUTPUT/working_districts_state.csv")
## Creating data frame
DISTRICT <- c("Alappuzha","Ernakulam","Idukki","Kannur","Kasaragod","Kollam","Kottayam","Kozhikode","Malappuram","Palakkad","Pathanamthitta","Thiruvananthapuram","Thrissur","Wayanad")
ST_NM <- rep("Kerala",length(DISTRICT))
reg.cases <- sample(0:250,length(DISTRICT), replace=T)
nr1 <- data.frame(DISTRICT, ST_NM, reg.cases)

india.dist <- readShapeSpatial("./shapes2/2011_Dist.shp")
india.dist@data <- merge(india.dist@data,nr1[,c(1,3)],by="DISTRICT")
india.dist@data$id <- rownames(india.dist@data)
ss.fort <- fortify(india.dist)
ss.fort1 <- merge(ss.fort, india.dist@data, by="id")

d <- ggplot() +
     geom_polygon(data = ss.fort1,
                  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=reg.cases)) +
     coord_equal()
```

I have two issues: 
1. I want to plot a state separately. I sub-set the shape file and try to plot using similar code. Problem arises when I use fortify command. The command creates an id column with ID extracted from original data i.e. india.dist and not the sub file. So when I merge state.fort with state@data, I do not get proper merge. I am still perplexed as I do not know how to reset ID.

```
state <- kr
state@data$id <- rownames(state@data)
state.fort <- fortify(state)
state.fort1 <- merge(state.fort, state@data, by="id")
unique(state.fort[,c(4:7)])
     hole piece  id group
1    FALSE     1   7   7.1
363  FALSE     1 173 173.1
719  FALSE     1 232 232.1
1384 FALSE     1 277 277.1
1960  TRUE     2 277 277.2
2013 FALSE     1 288 288.1
2561 FALSE     1 314 314.1
3018 FALSE     1 320 320.1
3349 FALSE     1 321 321.1
3753 FALSE     1 358 358.1
4144 FALSE     1 422 422.1
4735 FALSE     1 436 436.1
5204 FALSE     1 567 567.1
5663 FALSE     1 571 571.1
6292 FALSE     1 610 610.1

state@data
             DISTRICT  ST_NM ST_CEN_CD DT_CEN_CD censuscode reg.cases id
1           Alappuzha Kerala        32        11        598       259  1
2           Ernakulam Kerala        32         8        595       769  2
3              Idukki Kerala        32         9        596        42  3
4              Kannur Kerala        32         2        589        50  4
5           Kasaragod Kerala        32         1        588        38  5
6              Kollam Kerala        32        13        600       381  6
7            Kottayam Kerala        32        10        597        63  7
8           Kozhikode Kerala        32         4        591       237  8
9          Malappuram Kerala        32         5        592        95  9
10           Palakkad Kerala        32         6        593        31 10
11     Pathanamthitta Kerala        32        12        599        30 11
12 Thiruvananthapuram Kerala        32        14        601        97 12
13           Thrissur Kerala        32         7        594        99 13
14            Wayanad Kerala        32         3        590        39 14
```

2. Second issue is that: I suspect that the ggplot is not matching data (cases) to district properly. It is mismatching the data by giving wrong shade to wrong areas. I do not know how to check that such mismatch is not happening and if it is happening then how to fix it. I think this issue also involves handling ID in shape file.

I appreciate any guidance on the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it one idea you. After exchanging all comments, I think this is what you are probably after. If you need to create all maps, just delete `[1:2]` in the `lapply()`. You want to also check min and max values for `reg.cases`. In the current example, I have 24 and 240. Your real data would have different values. Adjust limits in `scale_fill_gradientn()`. Finally, make sure that you delete `[1:2]` in the final line. Sorry for being short, but this is what I can do for you now with my time limit.

```
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

### Import data. I am using Mac here.
india <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "2011_Dist", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Just get data for the district names in nr1.
temp <- subset(india, DISTRICT %in% nr1$DISTRICT)

### Add reg.cases by merging the two
x <- merge(temp, nr1, by = "DISTRICT")

### Get district names for the lapply part.
ana <- x$DISTRICT

### Subset data, get reg.cases value, fortify the SPdataframe,
### add reg.cases to the fortified data frame. Then, draw graphics.

foo <- lapply(ana[1:2], function(y){

             temp <- subset(x, x@data$DISTRICT == y)
             whatever <- temp@data$reg.cases
             temp2 <- fortify(temp) %>%
                      mutate(hue = whatever)

             g <- ggplot() +
                  geom_map(data = temp2, map = temp2,
                           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id, group = group,
                           fill = hue)) +
             scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(24, 240),
                                  colors = c("blue", "red"),
                                  name = "reg.cases") +
             coord_map() + 
             theme_map()
             g
           })

 # If you print all maps, delete [1:2] in the following line.
 invisible(mapply(ggsave, file=paste0(ana[1:2], ".png"), plot = foo))
```

[image]
[image]

**DATA**

```
nr1 <- structure(list(DISTRICT = structure(1:14, .Label = c("Alappuzha", 
"Ernakulam", "Idukki", "Kannur", "Kasaragod", "Kollam", "Kottayam", 
"Kozhikode", "Malappuram", "Palakkad", "Pathanamthitta", "Thiruvananthapuram", 
"Thrissur", "Wayanad"), class = "factor"), ST_NM = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Kerala", class = "factor"), 
reg.cases = c(54L, 84L, 45L, 137L, 140L, 171L, 152L, 20L, 
57L, 184L, 25L, 103L, 94L, 215L)), .Names = c("DISTRICT", 
"ST_NM", "reg.cases"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Now in India we cannot use the map as given in GADM. They exclude so called disputed territory. We have to include disputed territory else there is prison imprisonment. If we use GADM life is easier, but I have to use shape file [link](https://github.com/datameet/maps).   So I have to go via shape file and there the problem with mismatching ID arises.

Comment: @vikram I see. Unfortunately, I do not have enough time to look into the data. But, I guess the data is arranged in a similar way? As you showed in `state@data`, there are names for district. You can subset the data applying my code above and see how it goes.

Comment: @vikram Will you be able to provide `working_districts_state.csv` to us? At least a minimum reproducible data of the file would do.

Comment: I have added reproducible data frame as suggested by you. I hope this works.

Comment: @vikram Thanks for adding the data. Can I clarify one thing? Do you use `merge()` because you want to add `reg.cases` to india@data?

Comment: @vikram I am not sure if you need to worry about ID in the end. If I am not mistaken, after merging, you would subset data by district. So I do not see any clear reason why you care about ID.

Comment: You are absolutely right that I can subset the data using: `india.dist[india.dist$ST_NM== "Kerala",]` but the map matches the data (which use to fill colour) with ID. If I subset then the data it keeps the same ID (rownames as shown in code above.) This mixes the ID and wrong colours are matched to wrong IDs. So I thought venturing in ID may be helpful.

Comment: @vikram I thought you would subset using `DISTRICT` rather than `ST_NM`. I am confused. As for color, I think you would need to specify breaks in `scale_fill_continuous()`. Then, right colors would appear in your map.

Comment: @vikram I revised my answer. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort. I think I can take it forward from here.

Comment: @vikram Pleasure to help you.